# -9 modulo 12 is 3. Should get -9

Tags: modular-arithmetic

**STEP 1:** Divide Dividend (-9) from Divisor (12).

```
-9 / 12 = -0.75
```

Where,

`0` is whole part.

`75` is fractional part.

**STEP 2:** Whole part from the result of **STEP 1** to be multiplied by Divisor (12).

```
0 * 12 = 0
```

**STEP 3:** Subtract result from **STEP 2** from Dividend (-9).

```
-9-0 = -9
```

Whereas, The Actual answer is 3. Where am I missing?

Comment: $-9=-1\times12+3$

Comment: Modulo $12$ means up to multiples of $12$. Since $-9+1\cdot 12=3$, the answer can be $3$. But of course $-9=3$ in $\Bbb Z/12$, because $12=0$.

Comment: What about this article? https://divisible.info/Modulo/What-is-1-mod-12.html

Comment: @DietrichBurde Can you provide complete answer with step and article to refer for practising Modulo.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, Whats that `Z` symbol is?

Comment: $\Bbb Z=\{\cdots, -4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,\cdots\}$ is the ring of integers.

Comment: And $\Bbb Z/12$ is the ring of integers modulo 12. It's common to use the set of residues $\{0, 1, 2, \dots, m-1\}$ when working in modulus $m$, but it may be convenient to use a different residue set. Eg, for mod $9$ we might use $\{-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Residue_systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integer division of $a$ by $d$ is defined the following way:
$$a = qd + r$$
Where $d$ is divisor, $q$ is quotient, and $r$ is the remainder, for which $$0 \le r < |d|$$ Check reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division). This is an important thing to keep in mind while doing modular arithmetic and working with congruences.

For your case:
$$ -9 = 12q + r$$
The $q$ which gives the biggest $r$ which falls in the range discussed above is $q = -1$ (which is actually **integer floor** of the $-0.75$ you got in your algorithm). So if you decide to go your way, you should take the **integer floor** of the result obtained in **STEP 1**.
$$ -9 = 12*(-1) + 3$$

Answer (score 1):

Following your algorithm...

You get $-0.75$ from the division. You are reading that as $0$ for the integer part and $.75$ for the rest. But the next lowest integer under $-0.75$ is $-1$. So if you want to follow this algorithm, you should be using $-1$ for the integer part (and $+0.25$ for the fractional part):

$$-9-(\stackrel{\downarrow}{-1})(12)=-9+12=3$$

Comment: $\bar1\,.25$ as we used to say in far-off logarithm calculation days.